# PCL: Why so much dynamic allocation and raw pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, pcl

I've been working with PCL lately, in conjunction with ROS, and have been looking through some of their examples.

I am by no means an expert at c++, but I was under the impression that good style avoids raw pointers/dynamic allocation as much as possible. In addition, that shared pointers are on a as necessary protocol since they necessitate a reference manager.

I feel like the PCL tutorials are filled to the brim with these kinds of things, dynamic allocation and shared pointers, examples: [link1](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/cluster_extraction.html) [link2](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/statistical_outlier.html) [link3](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/cylinder_segmentation.html).

I'm just curious if/why this is necessary, if only to understand the c++ better.

Comment: Personally I do not trust code written "everything in main". IMO this is very bad practice. Doesn't meter this is just demo code. Anything what size depends on runtime parameter has to be on heap so I do not consider this as a problem. Looks like you are to worry about microoptimization.

Comment: If you look at the code, you see there are no calls to `delete` from the client.  This suggests that the framework is managing the pointers, and is the one responsible for deallocating the memory.  If the framework doesn't manage the memory, then the code has memory leaks.

Comment: Note PCL 1.0 was released March 2011, when C++11 implementations were only partial and experimental, so using `std::unique_ptr` in the API would have limited portability. And `std::make_unique` didn't exist at all.

Comment: I love acronyms.  Are you talking about Point Cloud Library or the HP Printer Language PCL?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews IMO,  HP Printer Control Language (PCL) gets the upper hand -- it's been around much longer, but I don't think HP has a patent on the name (unlike IBM).  Curious to know if the Point Cloud people were not aware of the probable confusion.